# SerialPort is Open but throws NullReferenceException on BytesToRead

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, serial-port, unity3d-unet

I have A SerialPort created, and can check it is not null, and that [SerialPort.IsOpen()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.ports.serialport.isopen(v=vs.110).aspx) returns true.
But when I check the [BytesToRead](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.ports.serialport.bytestoread(v=vs.110).aspx) Property I get a NullReferenceException.

```
NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
  System.IO.Ports.WinSerialStream.get_BytesToRead ()
  System.IO.Ports.SerialPort.get_BytesToRead ()
  (wrapper remoting-invoke-with-check) 
  System.IO.Ports.SerialPort:get_BytesToRead ()
  ...
```

I can step through with the debugger and see that immedietly before the BytesToRead call, the Serial Port is Instantiated and Open, but the debugger can't reach certain properties, including BytesToRead.

```
"System.IO.Ports.SerialPort"
    base: "System.IO.Ports.SerialPort"
    BaseStream: {System.IO.Ports.WinSerialStream}
    BaudRate: 9600
    BreakState: false
    BytesToRead: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
    BytesToWrite: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
    CDHolding: false
    CtsHolding: true
    DataBits: 8
    DiscardNull: System.NotImplementedException: The requested feature is not implemented.
    DsrHolding: false
    DtrEnable: false
    Encoding: {System.Text.ASCIIEncoding}
    Handshake: None
    IsOpen: true
    NewLine: "\r\n"
    Parity: None
    ParityReplace: System.NotImplementedException: The requested feature is not implemented.
    PortName: "COM3"
    ReadBufferSize: 4096
    ReadTimeout: 50
    ReceivedBytesThreshold: System.NotImplementedException: The requested feature is not implemented.
    RtsEnable: false
    StopBits: One
    WriteBufferSize: 2048
    WriteTimeout: -1
```

What could be going wrong?

Comment: The Port in question, COM3, can be used with another tool to successfully communicate with the device i'm talking to.  So I think I can rule out the USB cable, Device, and Port.
I am running inside Unity 2017.4.

Comment: I hoped to step into the Getter for BytesToRead, but my debugger won't go into it.  The OS is Windows 10 (up to date).  I believe the same code used to work (unchanged) on a Mac (only change was the different port string).  But the code will not find any ports at all on the Mac now... this may be a separate issue

Comment: Note - https://sourceforge.net/projects/serialportnet/ is 99% API compatible, open source, and reliable.  I recommend migrating to this library.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems this has been a bug for Unity since 2016.
They have "Postponed" working on it.

A Workaround is to use Experimental .NET 4.6 version, if you can migrate to that in your project without other problems.

https://issuetracker.unity3d.com/issues/serialport-bytestoread-returns-null-reference

Comment: Sadly, that is not the only bug with the serialport in Unity. I suggest you don't use that at-all. Buy a plugin or make your own with C++. It's not hard if you have basic C++ background